# Can I update two fields in a single set statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update a flag and a remark field using a case statement:

```
update [TEMP] 
set FLAG = 
(
case when len(Country) > 3 or len(country) < 3 --or len(country) = 0
then 0 else 1
case when 
)
```

I also want to update the field remark with 'Invalid Country' for the first case statement and then 'Invalid date' for the next case statement.

Comment: SQL Server. added tag.

Comment: regardless of RDBMS you have syntax error: `CASE` should be terminated with `END`, not with `CASE WHEN`

Comment: Do you want to update both columns `FLAG` and `Remark`, using the same condition?

Comment: Yes @FelixPamittan, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it is not possible to update two fields in one `SET column_name = CASE WHEN ... THEN .. ELSE ... END` statement. 
You need to create `SET column_name = sql_expression` for each column.

In your sample:

```
update [TEMP] 
set FLAG = 
(
case when len(Country) != 3 --or len(country) = 0
then 0 else 1 end
),
date = (case when date < getDate() then getDate() else null end ),
remark = 
( case when len(Country) != 3 then 'Invalid Country'
   when date < getDate() then 'Invalid date'
   else null end)
```

However some other DBMS (like Oracle) offer:

```
SET (column_name, column_name, ...) = (subquery4)
```

It would be possible there:

```
SET (column_name1, column_name2)  = 
    (Select CASE WHEN ... THEN .. ELSE ... END,
            CASE WHEN ... THEN .. ELSE ... END ..
```

The other story are triggers (they allow you to modify the other fields when you modify just one field - but it's maybe too far away from your question already).

Comment: Is it not possible to do this in the same case statement instead of writing a new case statement? For example, if the value is 0 from the first case statement, then set Remark = 'Invalid Country' ?

Comment: No. Your CASE is assigning value. Inside one assignment you are not able to assign some other field.

Comment: @sharktooth , no you cannot do so in single case when ,case statement can only assign value not update. i'd go with what dcieslak wrote.

Answer (score 2):

To set two columns, you would need a statement of the form:

```
  UPDATE [TEMP]
     SET col1 = expr1 
       , col2 = expr2
```

Where `expr1` and `expr2` are expressions that evaluate to the values you want to assign to each column. Those could be simple literals, or more complex expressions, such as CASE expressions.

As an outline of an example:

```
  UPDATE [TEMP]
     SET flag   = CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END
       , remark = CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END
```

The expressions can be more involved. For example you could nest another CASE expression, concatenation, etc. The expressions just have to return a value. It's not clear what values you want to assign to the columns, under what conditions.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Q: *It is simple, for each row if a record in the country column is more than 3 characters long then set the flag to 0 and set REMARK = 'Invalid Country'. Similarly, if the ISDATE(date_column) = 0 then set flag to 0 and set REMARK = 'Invalid Country'*

A: To do something simple like that...

```
  UPDATE [TEMP]
     SET flag   
         = CASE
           WHEN LEN(country) <> 3
           THEN 0
           WHEN ISDATE(date_column) = 0 
           THEN 0 
           ELSE 1
           END
       , remark
         = CASE
           WHEN LEN(country) <> 3
           THEN 'Invalid Country'
           WHEN ISDATE(date_column) = 0 
           THEN 'Invalid Date'      -- ?spec says set to 'Invalid Country'? 
           ELSE ''
           END
```

Comment: The value for flag will either be 0 or 1 depending on how the validation evaluates, at the same time Remark will have a comment like 'Invalid Country' when the validation fails(0) - Can this be done in the same case statement?

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression* not a *statement*. To update two columns, you need to assign a value to each. And no, it's not possible to reference the return from `expr1` in `expr2`. If you had a more concrete example of what you are trying to achieve (sample rows before, and after the update) it would be possible to write a statement in a different form, using an inline view and a JOIN operation. The syntax to achieve that it depends on which RDBMS you are using. Given the specification as it is, we'd just be guessing.

Comment: It is simple, for each row if a record in the country column is more than 3 characters long then set the flag to 0 and set REMARK = 'Invalid Country'. Similarly, if the ISDATE(date_column) = 0 then set flag to 0 and set REMARK = 'Invalid Country' ?

Comment: A CASE expression returns a *value*. To return *two* values... e.g. to return a "`0`" to assign to one column (`flag`), and to return a different value "`'Invalid Country'`" to assign to another column (`remark`)... that would require *two* expressions. A CASE expression is like any other expression... it gets evaluated and it returns a value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the logic of deciding whether a value is valid in one place only, to remove the duplicate code, then you can separate the logic of *deciding validity* and the *setting of the values*.

You can do this with using a CTE like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #peter(id INT PRIMARY KEY, Flag BIT, 
                    Country VARCHAR(30), date DATE, remark VARCHAR(100));

INSERT #peter
    ( id, Flag, Country, date, remark )
VALUES  
    ( 1, 0, 'SWE', '2015-06-01', NULL ),
    ( 2, 0, 'NK', '2016-06-10', NULL );

WITH peter AS (
        SELECT id ,
               Flag ,
               Country ,
               date ,
               remark,
               CASE WHEN date < GETDATE() THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS isValidDate,
               CASE WHEN LEN(Country) != 3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS isValidCountry
        FROM #peter
        )
UPDATE p
    SET   p.Flag = isValidCountry
        , p.date = CASE WHEN isValidDate = 1 THEN NULL ELSE GETDATE() END 
        , p.remark = CASE 
                        WHEN isValidCountry = 0 AND isValidDate = 0 THEN 'Date and Country is invalid'
                        WHEN isValidDate = 0 THEN 'Date is invalid'
                        WHEN isValidCountry = 0 THEN 'Country is invalid'
                    END  
FROM peter p
```

... or by performing the logic in CROSS APPLY like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #peter(id INT PRIMARY KEY, Flag BIT, 
                    Country VARCHAR(30), date DATE, remark VARCHAR(100));

INSERT #peter
        ( id, Flag, Country, date, remark )
VALUES  ( 1, 0, 'SWE', '2015-06-01', NULL ),
        ( 2, 0, 'NK', '2016-06-10', NULL );


UPDATE p
   SET    p.Flag = cntry.isValidCountry
        , p.date = CASE WHEN dt.isValidDate = 1 THEN NULL ELSE GETDATE() END 
        , p.remark = CASE 
                        WHEN cntry.isValidCountry = 0 AND dt.isValidDate = 0 THEN 'Date and Country is invalid'
                        WHEN dt.isValidDate = 0 THEN 'Date is invalid'
                        WHEN cntry.isValidCountry = 0 THEN 'Country is invalid'
                    END 

FROM #peter p
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN date < GETDATE() THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) dt(isValidDate)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(Country) != 3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) cntry(isValidCountry)
```